Можно ли использовать слово конфигурация по отношению к лапше быстрого приготовления?
Например: Я завариваю лапшу быстрого приготовления и не добавлю в неё сушенные овощи.
Это лапша быстрого приготовления с конфигурацией скажем 1.
Я добавлю в неё сушенные овощи и это будет конфигурация номер 2.
Можно ли назвать лапшу без овощей и с овощами, лапшой с разными конфигурациями?

лучше подобрать другой, более подходящий эпитет, так как блюдо-еда не является набором видимых форм - фигур.

Спасибо за ответ

Если у вас отличие только в том, есть овощи или нет, то, возможно, не стоит это называть конфигурацией, если же более одного пункта отличий, то можно и назвать, лучше  сопроводить вариативными картинками
